# How do you make it so a file gets the old number and adds to it?

Tags: java, file

what we want to happen is when a file saves we dont want it to overwrite the old one we want it to add to the old number in the file
This is the code for the writing of the file so far

```
public void save() throws IOException{
    if (Playtime.hascreatedfolder = false){
        File f = new File("plugins/PlayerTime/");
        f.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(player.getDisplayName() + ".txt");
        //f.createNewFile();
        try {
            BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            w.write(getTime());
            w.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

what we want to happen is for it to get the old number add to it and put the new number in Eg. if it had 1:5:21 and a player had played for an hour we will want 2:5:21 but we get 1:0:0 instead.

Comment: Please try to write questions and headings more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You never actually read from the file. Here's some possible tips:

- Uncomment your create file logic and wrap it in a `f.exists()` check.
  You might also want to do an exists check on `f` before calling
  `mkdirs`.
- If the file exists, read in the value for the current player time and
  store it in a variable. Then increment the variable based on the new
  player time.
- Overwrite the existing value in the file.

I would recommend a [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), it will make your life easier.